# @Scope ( INTERFACES ) equivalent for XML

Tags: xml, spring, annotations, scope, request

I'm trying to do this (code) in old school xml.

```
@Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)   
    public MyInterface createInterface() {
        return connectionRepository().getPrimaryConnection(MyInterface.class);
    }
```

I've tried to do this:

```
    <bean id="myBean" class="a.b.c.MyInterface"
        factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="create"
        scope="request">
        <constructor-arg value="a.b.c.MyInterface"></constructor-arg>
        <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
    </bean>
```

But i got:

> Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy12 implementing java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [a.b.c.MyInterface] for property 'myBean': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how i finally got it working. skaffman was digging really close:

```
<bean id="factory"
    class="a.b.c.Factory"
    scope="request">
</bean>

<bean id="facebook" class="a.b.c.MyInterface"
    factory-bean="factory" factory-method="createObject"
    scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

Define your bean:

```
package com.bit.impl;

public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean{
     ....
     ....
}
```

Add this code in your app-context.xml

```
<bean id="bean" class="com.bit.impl.MyBeanImpl" scope="session" >
     <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

Now, if you want to test your bean, you need add next configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="session">
                <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And that's all!

I hope this useful!

Best regards!

Comment: By the way, I forgot say you, you need CGLib jar and xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd"> XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your XML example doesn't seem to be equivalent to the Java version - where's the call to `connectionRepository().getPrimaryConnection`?  Alaos, the error message refers to a property `myBean`, whereas you've defined a bean by that name, not a property. I'm wondering if your error message actually came from that XML fragment, or a different one.

That aside, your problem may have something to do with the fact that you're specifying `class`, `factory-bean` and `factory-method` all at the same time. You generally only specify two of those, not all 3.

Try omitting `class`, just leaving `factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="create"`. Spring will infer the type of your bean from the return type of the factory method.